# How to fold directory trees in VScode with a shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use a MacBook. I want to fold all the directory trees in VScode using a shortcut at once.

Please tell me what that shortcut is.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an unbound command:

> File: Collapse Folders in Explorer
>
> `workbench.files.action.collapseExplorerFolders`

Search for that in `Keyboard Shortcuts` and click on the `+` sign to its left - enter the keybinding you want to use.

Comment: Atom editor used to have dozen of little quality-of-life features like this. I miss it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Click space on the selected folder to fold/unfold it

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. I wanna fold all of them at once.